# SQL Query that filters OUT the first and last row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sap-data-services

I'm working with SAP Data Services, and have a table that I'm trying to filter. Nothing I can think of in SAP would work, however if I use a SQL query that might.

My questions is: How do I make a query that will filter out the first and last row in a table?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  Please tag the question only with the database you are actually using.  Also, this question does not provide enough information to answer a question.  What does the table look like?

Comment: What defines what's first and what's last?

Comment: It will also help if you state what you mean by "first" and "last": is there some field, for example date/time, that allows you to order the rows? or more likely is there some numeric sequential ID that naturally orders the rows? SQL itself doesn't have any concept of "first" and "last" within a table.

Comment: There are no first and last rows in SQL tables.  The physical arrangement of the rows should never be assumed.  What you are asking is how to filter out the first and last row from a result set.

Comment: What if there is only one row? Only two rows?

Comment: sorry, Yes I have a three columns, ROW_ID, RECORD_TIMESTAMPT, and TRANSACTION_NO.

Comment: Im using SQL Server...

Comment: and you will want to order by (define first and last on basis of) ?

Comment: Well that's what im asking... So has anyone filtered out the first and last row by using a ROW_ID column, that numbers each row?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ROW_ID, RECORD_TIMESTAMP, TRANSACTION_NO FROM MyTable
EXCEPT
SELECT TOP(1) ROW_ID, RECORD_TIMESTAMP, TRANSACTION_NO FROM MyTable ORDER BY ROW_ID ASC
EXCEPT
SELECT TOP(1) ROW_ID, RECORD_TIMESTAMP, TRANSACTION_NO FROM MyTable ORDER BY ROW_ID DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from MY_TABLE
where TRANSACTION_NO > (select min(TRANSACTION_NO) from MY_TABLE)
    and TRANSACTION_NO < (select max(TRANSACTION_NO) from MY_TABLE)
```

You can substiute whichever column you wish for TRANSACTION_NO (ROW_ID, etc.) to match what constitutes "first" and "last" for your data.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from (
   select t.*, 
          row_number() over (order by ROW_ID) as rn, 
          count(*) over () as total_count
   from the_table
) t 
where rn > 1 and rn < total_count;
```

If your definition of "first" and "last" is not defined through the ordering of the `ROW_ID` then you need to adjust the `order by ROW_ID` in the `over(...)` clause of the window function.